# Get dynamically loaded html using WKWebView swift

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, html-parsing, wkwebview

I'm been trying to load HTML from websites that have dynamic/lazy loading. So far the only solution I have seen work is by using a WebView and then using a delay (`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0)`) before calling the `evaluateJavaScript` method. See below:

```
import SwiftSoup
import WebKit

private let myWebView: WKWebView = {
    let prefs = WKPreferences()
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.preferences = prefs
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    return webView
}()

var allProducts: [Element] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myWebView.navigationDelegate = self  
      
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://shop.coles.com.au/a/national/specials/search/coles-weekly-specials?pageNumber=1")
    myWebView.load(URLRequest(url: myURL!))

}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        
        myWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") { [self]  result, error in        

            guard let htmlContent = result, error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlContent as! String)
                       
                allProducts = try doc.select("header").array()

            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }

    }
        
}
```

The problem with this is that having a fixed delay is vey risky/inefficient as it may not load all data or it may waste time. I though of implementing a while loop on the code so that it repeats the evaluation until it finds the data (see blow):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    while allProducts.count < 1 {
        myWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") { [self]  result, error in

            guard let htmlContent = result, error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlContent as! String)
                       
                allProducts = try doc.select("header").array()

            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
        
}
```

But when I ran this the console responded very unexpectedly and I don't think it the ran the evaluation code even once. I assume that you cannot call the `evaluateJavaScript` method more than once on a particular load.

Does anyone know any workarounds to this code, or any other way to load dynamically loaded HTML. Any help would be highly appreciated!!!!